# FileInputStream without Creating an Actual File using Java

Tags: java, file-io

I was wondering if there was any way to create a FileInputStream object from just a file object without creating an actual file on the file system? What I am attempting to do is create a file object with some information, and then upload that file somewhere else. I have no need for it to be on the local file system. I know that I could just create a temp folder and then delete it afterwards, but was wondering if it was possible to not do it that way?

Comment: You could use `tmpfs` on Unix or a ramdisk on Windows. A ByteArrayInputStream is likely to be the simplest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What I am attempting to do is create a file object with some
>   information, and then upload that file somewhere else

In that case you should not work with any file-related classes at all. Instead, crate a byte array, which you can tread as an `InputStream` via `ByteArrayInputStream`.

Answer (score 5):

You are probably looking for a `ByteArrayInputStream` or something similar.

A file input stream reads from a file on disk, that is its purpose. By the way, a `File` object in Java does not really represent a file, but rather the path pointing to a (potential) file on disk.

Comment: +1 You can use a ByteArrayOutputStream to help you build the data for the "file"

Comment: I am having to call the following method which I cannot change, it's from the VersionOne API:                                      createAttachment(String name, String fileName, InputStream stream) throws AttachmentLengthExceededException, ApplicationUnavailableException

Comment: @ReidMac  So what is the problems exactly?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Nothing, just providing more information, sorry. Trying this now.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a [memory stream](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/MemoryByteArrayOutputStream.htm), your file is stored in the memory instead of the file system